# cleveref package and conditional page references

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, conditionals

From the `cleveref` package, I am using `cref` in conjunction with `cpageref`:

```
\newcommand{\cpref}[1]{\cref{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
```

because I found it practical, e.g. when referencing a figure a few pages away, to also include a reference to the page.
However, this is less useful, if the figure appears on the same page as its reference.

Is there a way to make `cpageref` in above macro conditional on where the referee appears? For example, to not show a "page X" if it's on page X.

**EDIT: Solution**

For completeness, this is how I changed the command:

```
\newcommand{\cpref}[1]{\cref{#1} (\vpageref{#1})}
```

by loading `varioref` before `cleveref`.

Comment: Have you seen the varioref package? In particular, it can be combined nicely with cleveref....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `\usepackage{varioref}` before cleveref then use `\Vref`.